# Is there a way to create two html tables from XML with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I found this webpage to manipulate the dom with xml nodes. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_applications.asp

What i need to do: two html tables generated from XML and I need to show paragraph from XML too.

This is what I could write so far. The problem is I couldn't retrive as text (it is in div id='showCD') and as tables (table id="demo,demo2") in my HTML document. If I left only one table or div, i can extract the data from XML.

Do you have any suggestions how to have all of them?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id='showCD'></div>
<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>
<br><br>
<table id="demo2"></table>    

<script>
displayCD(0);

function displayCD(i) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this, i);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml, i) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; 
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
    document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML =
    "Artist: " +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Title: " +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Year: " + 
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
</script>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc2() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Resources:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_app_first

cd_catalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Eros</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>One night only</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1998</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.10</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1973</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.50</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1999</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1971</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Stop</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1991</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Stax Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1968</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Red</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>London</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: 1. Please click edit, then the button that looks like `[<>]` and 2. post a [mcve] of the xml and the processing. Assuming getting the file from the server works, we do not nbeed the AJAX in the snippet

Comment: Have you considered using XSLT instead? XSLT is precisely meant for transforming any XML into other formats, including HTML. All major browsers natively support XSLT 1.0, and there are JavaScript implementations of XSLT 2.0 as well.

Comment: It is not clear which output you expect. For instance, you speak of "paragraph" but where in your code do you deal with that? Secondly, why you perform a request for the same XML source twice?  Which is the desired content order rand layout of the tables you speak of?

Answer (score 0):

Just parameterize your functions `loadXMLDoc(el)` and `myFunction(xml,el)` for accepting target html element for which you will load content dynamically. Something like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('demo1');loadXMLDoc('demo2');">Get my CD collection</button>
<br><br>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Table 1<table id="demo1"></table></td>
<td>Table 2<table id="demo2"></table></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc(el) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this,el);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml,el) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById(el).innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to create the second table with different "node values" like company and year

Comment: just write yet another function which parses your other XML and constructs a table from it and use it in place of `myFunction(xml,el)`

Comment: But i have only one XML

Comment: Listen, How you will transform your XML into html table - is your personal business. You can transform it in gazillion ways,  generate missing nodes/table cells, etc. Just turn-on your fantasy, and begin coding !

Comment: Yea i noticed the gazillion ways before i posted my question here. I couldn't make it work. I believe the purpose of this webpage is "helping each other"

Comment: What exactly means "I couldn't make it work" ? If you will supply more details of your problem in question maybe somebody will be able to help you.